# Extract or View Cloudkit data

Tags: ios, icloud

Recently an iOS app I use updated and broke half the features, and removed the other half. One such feature included an export to CSV.

I'd like to extract the data I'd been collecting via the app, of which backups are stored in iCloud (not iCloud Drive, but Cloudkit).

How can I view Cloudkit data?

The closest I've found is [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616397/export-data-from-cloudkit) which asks if there is an export function. There is also suggestions that cloudkit dashboard would display this data, but only for apps I have built myself, not apps I use but did not develop.

If the result is an SQLite database/JSON/PLists or some other machine format I don't mind, it doesn't have to be processed and user friendly

Comment: Do you have a [Mac to run software like PhoneView](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/15188/5472)? It’s not entirely clear what tool chain you are open to for a solve... Not all apps store the data locally but [some are amenable to jailbreak or iMazing access.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410092/5472)

Comment: I have a Mac yes, I'm also a developer though I've not worked on iOS apps myself, I'm happy to learn. If it takes me a while to do something at least I'll know how it can be done via the answer to this question. I did give PhoneView a try, but it didn't give me access to what I needed. Great if i want iMessage history etc, but I need data from a 3rd party application that backs up its data to cloudkit

Comment: Further digging allowed me to retrieve the database from a local backup, but sadly it's an encrypted realms database, which means the version in cloudkit is unlikely to be readable without developer intervention or decompiling the application